# ios bottom up animation

Tags: ios, objective-c

how to animate a UILabel from bottom to up in iOS, i did this in android like this

```
Animation bottomUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(_activity, R.drawable.bottom_up);
txtTitle.startAnimation(bottomUp);
```

bottom_up.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <translate android:fromYDelta="75%p" android:toYDelta="0%p" 
    android:fillAfter="true"
 android:duration="600"/>
</set>
```

is there any idea to do the same in iOS also?

Hi all thanks for your help. i figured it out in this way.

```
 CATransition *Sidetransition=[CATransition animation];
 Sidetransition.duration=0.7;
 Sidetransition.type=kCATransitionMoveIn;
 Sidetransition.subtype=kCATransitionFromTop;
 [lblTitle.layer addAnimation:Sidetransition forKey:nil];
```

Thanks.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the `xcode IDE` please don't use that tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add layer animation to label which is make movement up and down. Use below code. It may useful to you..

```
-(void)addUpDownAnimationForButton:(UILabel*)label
{      
    CABasicAnimation *moveAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    moveAnimation.duration = 5.0;
    moveAnimation.repeatCount=HUGE_VALF;
    moveAnimation.autoreverses=YES;
    moveAnimation.fromValue= [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, 0.0)];
    moveAnimation.toValue=[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [label.layer addAnimation:moveAnimation forKey:@"animatePosition"];
}
```

If you want remove this animation, remove animation from layer by

```
-(void)removeUpDownAnimationForButton:(UILabel*)label
{
    [label.layer removeAnimationForKey:@"animatePosition"];
}
```